# Log4j rolling file appender: include LAST timestamp in filename

Tags: java, log4j2

I fiddled around with a rolling file appender with autocompress to .gz, which gave me a lot of files like this:

- foo_bar_1.gz
- foo_bar_2.gz
- ...

and so on.

Next I changed the filePattern to "%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%d{HH-mm-ss}.log.gz" which included a timestamp into the filename. Unfortunately our system management division can't use the timestamp, as this timestamp does not reflect the LAST insertion into the log (or at least the timestamp when rolling and compressing occured).

Is there any way to make Log4j2 to change the filename of the logfile (and of course of the compressed file) to the timestamp of the last insertion?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any way to do that with standard log4j2, but I imagine you could write a custom appender that would change the file name when it rolls over before doing the compression.